# How to make sequential number and repeat it

Tags: php, for-loop

I would like to make a number sequential and repetitive to the beginning when it reaches the limit. For instance, the first number begins with 001, then 002, 003, and so on until it reaches 999. When it reaches 999, then the number will return to 01 and continues to repeat.

I currently have this loop:

```
$i = 001;
for ( $i; $i < 111; $i++)
{
echo str_pad ($i, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT), '<br>';
}
```

But how can I make that return to the first number and continues like before? I mean if the number reaches 999, it will back to 001, 002, 003, and so on.

Comment: This will be an infinite loop...

Comment: A little more context would be useful. As is I can only think of the 'but why' meme. ps: `if($i == 999){$i = 1}`.

Comment: minor formatting and grammar fixes.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKunst, you're inspiring me :)

Answer (score 1):

Even if I don't quite understand why you want to do that, this is your solution :

```
<?php

for ($i = 001, $max = 111; $i < $max; $i++)
{
    echo str_pad ($i, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT), '<br>';

    if ($i == $max - 1) { 
        $i = 001; 
    }
}
```

But this will cause an infinite loop of course.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. After I search in search engine, now I understand what is an infinite loop :)

Here is my trial:

`$i = 01;
  for ( $i; $i <= 10; $i++)
  {
   echo sprintf('%02d', $i) .'<br/>';

   if ( $i == 10 )
   {
    $i = 01;
    echo sprintf('%02d', $i) .'<br/>';
    // break;
   }
  }
`

Comment: One more question. How can I save each number in a session that will be stored in database? For example if someone would like to register in my website, he/she will get an unique number that will be stored in specific field, i.e. person A get 001, person B get 002, and so on. Then after person Z get 999, the next person will get 001 and so on

Comment: That's an entire other problem. You will have to save the current number as a row into a table in your database. Then on each view you fetch this number, you increment it (and if the number reaches your max you reset it). You then store it into session (many tutorials about that exist) and update the current row with your new number.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. I will try :)